# apache responding 403 to wordpress tinyMCE js requests

Tags: wordpress, apache, http

there is something strange happening on my server. It has worked like a charm with wordpress from 2.3 version, and I update it regularly. 
Today I updated to wordpress 4.1 and, when I tried to write a post, I found the tinyMCE editor completely unloaded. 
I then checked the console and I have a bunch of 403 errors, for requests like

```
http://www.ilparticolarenascosto.it/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/after-the-deadline/tinymce/plugin.js?v=20140527&wp-mce-4107-20141130
```

infact my hosting answers with a courtesy page (that doesn't even explain what's happening).

the strange thing is that if i try

```
http://www.ilparticolarenascosto.it/wp-content/plugins/jetpack/modules/after-the-deadline/tinymce/plugin.js
```

(without the ending `?v=20140527&wp-mce-4107-20141130` ! ) I can download the file regoularly.

What's happening? what can I do?
I have already reinstalled it, and the problem occours with firefox and chrome, so I think it's a server issue.

And, also, if the first link works to you, maybe it's not working because I'm behind a proxy? but,again, why?

Comment: I have updated wordpress every time there has been a new update, even once a month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The first link works for me. I am not sure why it is not working for you.

Clear your browser cache to rule out your browser as a cause

Check you webserver access logs. Access logs will have a response status for every request. It may be possible that some one is overwriting the 200 OK sent by apache

Comment: cleared cache, still having the bad behaviour. I cannot see the apache logs, it's a shared hosting unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
It was a security setting on the server, blocking urls with variables.
Wordpress inludes tinymce files with variable in the end:

```
wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js?wp-mce-4203-20150730
```

call your hoster to fix it

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the problem is ... Adblock.

Disable it, clean the browser cache, and reload the page. The Wordpress Editor will suddently appear.